# Envío automático de mail en yii2

Tags: yii2

Estoy intentando enviar automáticamente un correo electrónico faltando x días para una fecha. He leído en algunos foros que esto se puede hacer desde la consola de yii2, por lo que he creado una clase llamada mailController en el directorio console/controllers. El código de la clase es el siguiente:

```
namespace console\controllers;
```

use yii\console\Controller;

class mailController extends Controller {

```
//put your code here
public function sendMail($fecha, $dias, $proyecto) {
    \Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
            ->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => 'SyS CGA GADPO'])
            ->setTo('javier.aguilar@gporellana.gob.ec')
            ->setSubject('Sistema de Gestión de Auditorías Ambientales GADPO')
            ->setTextBody('Le recordamos que tiene programada una auditoría ambiental para el proyecto ' . $proyecto . ' el día ' . $fecha . '. Faltan ' . $dias . ' días')
            ->send();
}

public function actionSend() {
    foreach ($this->getAuditorias() as $rows) {
        $fecha = $rows['fecha'];
        $dias = $rows['dfaltantes'];
        $id = $rows['id_proyecto'];
        $proyecto = \frontend\Models\WorkPackages::findOne($id)['subject'];
        if ($dias == 15 || $dias == 10 || $dias == 5) {
            $this->sendEmail($fecha, $dias, $proyecto);
        }
    }
}

public function getAuditorias() {
    return \frontend\models\FecAuditoria::find()->where(['idestado' => 1])->all();
}
```

}

Intento ejecutar desde el cmd en Windows desde la ruta xammp/htdocs/yii2-starter

```
php yii mail/send
```

pero obtengo el error

```
Uknown command mail/send
```

No encuentro mucha información de como hacer esta última parte de ejecutar las funciones en la consola de yii2 para posteriormente hacerlo de forma autómatica con un cronjob

Comment: Hola Javier , yo normalmente  los controladores de comandos de consola los tengo en una carpeta llamada "commands" en la raiz del proyecto . intenta mover tu controller ahí

Answer (score 1):

Trata de escribir tu controlador en la carpeta "/commands"

> namespace app\commands;

Te dejo un ejemplo aqui de como seria un comando basico

En MyYii2App/commands/HelloController.php

```
<?php

namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;
use yii\console\ExitCode;

class HelloController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex($message = 'hello world')
    {
        echo $message . "\n";

        return ExitCode::OK;
    }
}
```

Y desde tu consola de windows desde la raiz del proyecto de Yii2 ejecuta el siguiente comando

> php yii hello

o lo que es lo mismo ( php yii "controllerName"/"actionName" )

> php yii hello/index

Y deberias ver algo como esto

> hello world